# Implement animated Button in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I wish to clone the effects of the button animations found in Candy Crush Saga.
And also I wish to know how to do such fluid & beautiful animations.
Is it possible with Cocos2d-iPhone?

**This is the link of Candy Crush Sage:**

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAMUWIqYN24

Is it done using image sequences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible. Just run animation on buttons normal sprite.

```
GTAnimSprite *frame_normal   = [GTAnimSprite spriteWithFile:@"play_button_normal.png"];
GTAnimSprite *frame_sel     = [GTAnimSprite spriteWithFile:@"play_button_selected.png"];
frame_sel.color = ccc3(128,128,128);

CCMenuItemSprite *plyBtn = [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:frame_normal
                                          selectedSprite:frame_sel
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(playBtnPress:) ];

plyBtn.position = ccp(size.width*0.77f, size.height*0.1f);

CCMenu *menu2 = [CCMenu menuWithItems:plyBtn, nil];
menu2.position = ccp(0.0f,0.0f);
[self addChild:menu2 z:2 ];
```

//Here is class file:`GTAnimSprite.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface GTAnimSprite : CCSprite
{
    bool bouncing;
    float counter;

}
@end
```

//Here is class file:`GTAnimSprite.mm`

```
#import "GTAnimSprite.h"

@implementation GTAnimSprite

-(void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];

    counter = 0.0f;

    bouncing = true;

    [self scheduleUpdate];
}

-(void)update:(ccTime)dt
{
    if (bouncing)
    {
        counter += dt;

        self.scaleX = ( (sin(counter*10) + 1)/2.0 * 0.1 + 1);
        self.scaleY = ( (cos(counter*10) + 1)/2.0 * 0.1 + 1);

        if (counter > M_PI*10){
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}

-(void)onExit
{
    [self unscheduleUpdate];

    [super onExit];
}

@end
```

**HERE IS XCODE SAMPLE SOURCE:  https://www.box.com/s/52i4xyznetyyc329evcu**

Comment: I have implemented similar behavior with CCActions.What's best performance wise, custom CCSprite (like this) or implement CCActions?

Comment: @KarlosZafra, Good to implement with CCActions. Show me code that you used with CCActions.

Comment: @Guru: This is working fine... no doubt in this... But when i simply create a sprite than it is working good, but when i use this sprite in ccMenuItemSprite it will be scaled vertically and in direction of positive x axis. That is , its sprites left side is fixed. How can i solved this? If you need further description than let me know.?

Comment: instead of running it on CCMenuItemSprite, run it on its normal and selected image.

Comment: Is it possible to implement this kind of buttons on website using jquery, css3, .... ?

Comment: Nice work. I would love to implement this code sometimes. However, I have a question @Guru, could you explain why you have used that sin(..), cos(..) in update method? Why it is necessary? Is there any formula related to this?

Comment: to get wave factor we used sin and cos in it, those sin and cos gives floating point value that gives smooth effect for buttons.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it using CCActions

First, I define the CCAction:

```
 id scaleHorDown = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:duration * 5/30.f scaleX:0.75f scaleY:1.0f];
 id scaleHorBouncing = [CCEaseBounceIn actionWithAction:scaleHorDown];
 id scaleVerDown = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:duration * 5/30.f scaleX:1.0f scaleY:0.65f];
 id scaleVerBouncing = [CCEaseBounceInOut actionWithAction:scaleVerDown];

 id shrink = [CCSequence actions:scaleHorBouncing,scaleVerBouncing, nil];

 id swell = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration: duration * 15/30.f scale:1.10f];
 id swellEase = [CCEaseElasticOut actionWithAction:swell];

 id resetScale = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:duration * 5/30.f  scale:1.0f];
 id resetScaleBouncing = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:resetScale];

 id buttonAction = [CCSequence actions: shrink, swellEase, resetScaleBouncing, nil];
```

Then I run the animation over the desired sprites when CCMenuItem is initialized

```
CCMenuItem aMenuItem = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:buttonNormalSprite
                         selectedSprite:buttonSelectedSprite
                         block:^(id sender) {
                            //play animation highlighting button
                            [buttonSelectedSprite runAction:buttonAction]];
                                                        }}];
```

In my case I'm only running the animation when the button is pressed.